# How can I get drawable from glide? Actually i want to return drawable from glide which load image and put into imageview

Tags: android, drawable, android-glide

Here is my code:

```
d.setBounds(15, 8, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM) {}
```

Comment: i want get drawable because i will utilise the uses of drawable function. thats why i want to get drawable from glide

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 20):

Use the latest version of Glide

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Kotlin:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imagePath)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                // some other reason.
                // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
            }
        })
```

Bitmap Size:

if you want to use the original size of the image use the default constructor as above, else You can pass your desired size for bitmap

```
into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(1980, 1080)
```

Java:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(path)
        .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
```